# composer php version error after uploading project to live server

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Hello i'm trying to run my laravel project on live server using shared hosting after i upload all project file and directory and open my domain address it gives me error

```
Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.8".
```

and yes i was set up the php version on composer.json as **"php": "^8.1.8",** and **"php": "^8.1.8"** on composer.lock and when i run the project in local machine it's running as expected without any error. i also check my php version on my shared hosting by using **php -v** and it's return:

```
PHP 8.1.8 (cli) (built: Jul 14 2022 13:17:16) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
```

and on my local machine using **php -v** it return:

```
PHP 8.1.8 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2022 23:04:29) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.8, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

i'm already find similar problem but none help to solve this...

Comment: Can you check which PHP version is composer pointing to?
`composer -vvv about 2>&1 | grep "PHP"`

Comment: @TeachMe it give me 
Running 2.2.12 (2022-04-13 16:42:25) with PHP 8.1.8 on Linux / 3.10.0-962.3.2.lve1.5.63.el7.x86_64
Reading ./composer.json (/home/arca3276/source-lib/device-viewer/composer.json)
Loading config file ./composer.json (/home/arca3276/source-lib/device-viewer/composer.json)
Checked CA file /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem: valid
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file

Comment: Try to remove composer.lock and run again composer install

Comment: @ErDiablo i try your suggestion to delete the composer.lock files and try to **composer install**, currently im using shared hosting so i unable to use **composer install** directly and use **composer install --no-scripts** insteed and generated other files/package manually using artisan commands but it still give me a same exact error as above

Comment: You need to find the root cause of it. I'm not sure why this is happening. You can try to ignore the suggestion for now for quick fix. `composer install --ignore-platform-req=php`

Comment: Which PHP version does your Apache (or nginx) use? `php -v` shows which version is used by the PHP shell, not by any webserver process

Comment: @NicoHaase i was check this via cpanel on **php version selector** and relize that my domain was pointing to **multiPHP version** (makes my domain point to default apache php version), i already describe on the answer below about the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to suggestion from @TeachMe and @ErDiablo, i finally know way to encounter this errors, first the composer installed on the project will need to regenerate using **composer install**

but since i'm using shared hosting so i using **composer install --no-scripts** insteed because the limitation to access the direcetory from hosting providers and after using that commands, continue with type:

```
php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
php artisan key:generate
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan package:discover
```

This will help to generate key, package, .env file, and clear cache.
after using all that commands, open your domain and everything should be done.

Notes:
if still got the same error it can be possible caused by the php selector that provided by cPanel i once get this error, it seems that the composer was confused to get php version (maybe that the shared hosting have multi php version installed) or host / domain was loaded the different php version with that provided from **php -v** so you will need to make your domain to use **php version selector** that provided by cpanel and make sure your domains not using **multiPHP Manager** and also make sure that the php version from php version selector point to the same version on composer.json (if you not using cpanel, you will need to find way to change the version via termial or ssh)